# ScrollViewer Not Filling Full Screen

Tags: wpf, xaml, scroll, fullscreen

I am trying to allow the ScrollViewer to take stretch and fit size of the screen but I'm not managing as it is still keeping the size of the listview.

Is there any way that this can be done?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <!-- code -->
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi... took your code and it worked for me: the scrollviewer get resized by the grid, and the grid by the window. ¿Am i getting you right?

Comment: Is there something above the grid.

Comment: It in a user control, might be that the there is something in the other window. I'll check

Comment: why do you have the list view inside a scroll viewer?  doesn't the listview template *already* have a scroll view?

Comment: I needed a scrollbar for the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had a StackPanel in the parent window as the above was in a UserControl. Changed the StackPanel to a DockPanel and worked.